# Is it legal to create an alternative implementation of proprietary game server?

Tags: copyright, software

There are various multiplayer MOBA or MMORPG games, that have no publicly available documentation for their proprietary server protocols, and which only have one official client that provides an access to their services - for free or for a fee. For example, World of Warcraft, Lineage, DotA, League of Legends, etc.

Would it be legal, under US and EU law, to reverse engineer their clients (using clean room engineering approach), document their client-server protocol, and recreate server software that would be compatible with the official client, but containing no copyrighted code by original authors?

Would it be also legal to charge for using such private server software?

Comment: A game is **more** than just the client or server protocol. It is also the art-assets and their location in the designed world, the text-assets... With that in mind, does this answer your problem: [How can one open a profitable MMORPG private server (server emulator) legally?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55388/how-can-one-open-a-profitable-mmorpg-private-server-server-emulator-legally)

Answer (score 0):

That is called a server emulator, and there a various server emulators for these games (especially WoW), but hosting a private server using such software may cause a risk of being sued, depending how it is done.